# Java Equation Plotting

Tags: java, c, plot, equation, graphic

We are in need of a Java API that evaluates and plot an equation we pass as a parameter. We DO NOT want to evaluate every single point of the plot to later make the plot, we want an API that does this for us

Comment: One possible solution for the royal "we" I believe is to use Matlab or Octave together with Java.

Comment: Can you explain how to use Octave? Or maybe a definition of how it works? Were kinda lost here...